# Update Or Add Data in Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, multidimensional-array

Hello i am creating a best recently product view based on php cookies. first of all whenever user view some data so i store cookie as follow

```
//by Creating Manually array
$cookieArr = array("productid"=>$row_category[0],"views"=>1);
setcookie("myshopping", $cookieArr, time() + (8640000 * 30), "/");
```

Which Output As follow

```
(
    [productid] => 27
    [views] => 1
)
```

Now When user visit another page as example if `35 number page` so output should be like

```
(
    [productid] => 27,35
    [views] => 1,1
)
```

this is not a problem to how to add this. the problem is i have to increement view if user visit same page again. for example if user visit 27 page again so arrray should like. means data is not add just update the views.

```
(
    [productid] => 27,35
    [views] => 2,1
)
```

i tried by

```
foreach ($cookieArr as $key => $value) {
  //Get all products
  $allProdcutid = $cookieArr["productid"];
}
//than checking
if(in_array($myproductid, $cookieArr['productid'])){
    echo "Avaibality";
}else{
    echo "exit";
}
```

*This is for demonstration.*

Comment: why comma seperated values ? why not create an array like :-`(
    [productid] => array(27,35),
    [views] => array(27=>2,35=>1)
)` . easy to update or add everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.*** you can create array like below:-

```
Array( 
  27=>1,
  35=>1
)
```

This will be even more easy to handle. keys are productid's and values are how many time they visited.

***2.*** Or modify your code like below:-

```
<?php

$myproductid = 27;
$cookieArr= array(
    'productid' => '27,35',
    'views' => '1,1'
);

if(in_array($myproductid, explode(',',$cookieArr['productid']))){
    $searched_key = array_search($myproductid,explode(',',$cookieArr['productid']));
    $views_array = explode(',',$cookieArr['views']);
    $views_array[$searched_key] +=1;
    $cookieArr['views'] = implode(',',$views_array);
}else{
    echo "exit";
}

print_r($cookieArr);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/973605

Comment: Its really great .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at multi dimensional arrays... https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

You can form your cookie array like the below

```
(
    [products] => [13=>array("views"=>1),27=>array("Views"=>4)]              
)
```

then you can use array_key_exists on the products array to find your product id or add it.

Below is the php code:

```
if(array_key_exists($myproductid,$cookie['products'])  
{
   $cookie['products'][$myproductid]['views']++;
}
else
{
   $cookie['products'][$myproductid]=array('views'=>1);
}
```

This way you can later add other properties than views to your product array...

Comment: This is my question.!

Answer (score -1):

You need to store your array with product_id as key and views as a value. For example,

```
(
27 => 1,
37 => 2
)
```

By this you just have to check the key of the array and increment its value.

For example if user visits product id 27.

Comment: This should be comment